# UK visa end date is before my intended travel date, is there a way to correct it?

Tags: visas, uk

My spouse's UK visa application appointment was on 23rd Sep 2016. We have mentioned intended travel date as 20th Nov 2016. We got the visa and the passport back on 07th Oct 2016 with mentioned visa validity from 04-Oct-2016 to 03-Nov-2016. Is there any chance to change the visa start date near to my intended travel date? Do you have any suggestion how to best achieve that?

My spouse is not in condition to travel in between visa start date & end date.

Comment: Don't contact us, contact the consulate.

Comment: I agree, the most expedient is to make a fresh application, but if you can get in to the VFS, they may be able to help you get the visa altered.

Answer (score 4):

You need to contact [UK Visas and Immigration](https://ukvi-international.faq-help.com/). It is possible by e-mail or by telephone (for which there is a charge).

Fuller details are not practical without the clarification requested from you.

The GWF number allocated to you during the application process and your date of birth will be required.